# How to change, edit, save /etc/hosts file from Azure Bash for Kubernetes?

Tags: linux, azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I uploaded a project to kubernetes and for its gateway to redirect the services, it requires the following:

```
127.0.0.1 app.my.project
127.0.0.1 event-manager.my.project
127.0.0.1 logger.my.project
```

and so on.

I can't run any sudo commands, so `sudo nano /etc/hosts` doesnt work. I tried `vi /etc/hosts` and it gives permission denied error. How can I edit /etc/hosts file or do some configuration on Azure to make it work like that?

**Edit:**

To give more information, I have uploaded a project to Kubernetes that has reverse-proxy settings.

So reaching the web-app of that project is not available via IP. Instead if I'm running the application locally, I have to edit the hosts file of the computer I'm using with

```
127.0.0.1 app.my.project
127.0.0.1 event-manager.my.project
127.0.0.1 logger.my.project
```

and so on. So whenever I type web-app.my.project its gateway redirects to web-app part and if I write app.my.project it redirects to app part, etc.

When I uploaded it to Azure Kubernetes Service it added `default-http-backend` on `ingress-nginx` namespace which created by itself. To expose these services, I opened the Http Routing option from Azure which gave me the loadbalancer at the left side of the image. So If I'm reading the situation correctly, (I'm most probably wrong though) it is something like the image below:

[image: AKS]

So, I added hostaliases to `kube-system`, `ingress-nginx` and `default` namespaces to make it like I edited a hosts file when I was running the project locally. But it still gives me that `default backend - 404` ingress error

**Edit 2:**

I have nginx-ingress-controller which allows the redirection as far as I understand. So, when I add hostaliases to it as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ingress-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ingress-nginx
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/port: '10254'
        prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    spec:
      hostAliases:
      - ip: "127.0.0.1"
      hostnames:
      - "app.ota.local"
      - "gateway.ota.local"
      - "treehub.ota.local"
      - "tuf-reposerver.ota.local"
      - "web-events.ota.local"
      hostNetwork: true
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller
          image: {{ .ingress_controller_docker_image }}
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
            - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
            - --udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          ports:
          - name: tcp
            containerPort: 8000
          - name: http
            containerPort: 80
          - name: https
            containerPort: 443
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
```

So when I edit yaml file as aforementioned, it gives the following error on Azure:

> Failed to update the deployment
> Failed to update the deployment 'nginx-ingress-controller'. Error: BadRequest (400) : Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: v1.Deployment.Spec: v1.DeploymentSpec.Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec.Spec: v1.PodSpec.HostAliases: []v1.HostAlias: readObjectStart: expect { or n, but found ", error found in #10 byte of ...|liases":["ip "127.0|..., bigger context ...|theus.io/scrape":"true"}},"spec":{"hostAliases":["ip "127.0.0.1""],"hostnames":["app.ota.local","g|...

If I edit the yaml file locally and try to run it from local kubectl which is connected to Azure, it gives the following error:

> serviceaccount/weave-net configured
> clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/weave-net configured
> clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/weave-net configured
> role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/weave-net configured
> rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/weave-net configured
> daemonset.apps/weave-net configured Using cluster from kubectl
> context: k8s_14
>
> namespace/ingress-nginx unchanged deployment.apps/default-http-backend
> unchanged service/default-http-backend unchanged
> configmap/nginx-configuration unchanged configmap/tcp-services
> unchanged configmap/udp-services unchanged
> serviceaccount/nginx-ingress-serviceaccount unchanged
> clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/nginx-ingress-clusterrole
> unchanged role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/nginx-ingress-role unchanged
> rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/nginx-ingress-role-nisa-binding
> unchanged
> clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/nginx-ingress-clusterrole-nisa-binding
> unchanged error: error validating
> "/home/.../ota-community-edition/scripts/../generated/templates/ingress":
> error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec):
> unknown field "hostnames" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec; if you choose
> to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
> make: *** [Makefile:34: start_start-all] Error 1

Comment: Hi Jeredriq Demas. Does @Rakesh Gupta ´s answer solve your issue?

Comment: @IvanM. sadly no, check my comment

Comment: Could you please provide more details on how you set up your cluster (loadbalancer/ingress/services, etc.)?  What k8s version are you using? And what are trying to achieve by editing hosts file?

Comment: @IvanM. I added more details to question, please check it :)

Comment: Just to make sure we are talking about the same things :)  Did you add ´.spec.hostAliases´ section to your pods and not to some dummy busybox pod?

Comment: @IvanM. I added a host-aliases pod with yaml given from this example: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/network/customize-hosts-file-for-pods/#default-hosts-file-content

Comment: So, you created that busybox pod from the example? But you should add that hostAliases section in your application pod´s yaml files. And you don´t need that host-aliases pod like in example.

Comment: @IvanM. thanks for the answer. Should I add it to web-application's pod or should I add it to loadbalancer's pod?

Comment: It depends on your app architecture. In general, every pod that must be aware of your hosts modifications should have .spec.hostAliases section. Let me know if that solves your issue, please.

Comment: @IvanM. I believe thanks to you I'm really close to solving this issue :D Please check the second edit in the question

Comment: You should correct indentation error at .spec.hostAliases (hostnames). The whole situation is very hard to understand. Why are trying to modify default nginx ingress? Do you really need those aliases? AKS K8s gives you a solution configuring loadbalancer - ingress - services - deployments (pods). Are you following some guide/tutorial? What is the current state of your cluster and what is the desired state? Please, check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip?tabs=azure-cli)

Answer (score 0):

> Adding entries to a
> Pod's /etc/hosts file provides Pod-level override of hostname
> resolution when DNS and other options are not applicable. You can add
> these custom entries with the HostAliases field in PodSpec.
>
> Modification not using HostAliases is not suggested because the file
> is managed by the kubelet and can be overwritten on during Pod
> creation/restart.

I suggest that you use [hostAliases](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/network/customize-hosts-file-for-pods/) instead

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hostaliases-pod
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "127.0.0.1"
    hostnames:
    - "app.my.project"
    - "event-manager.my.project"
    - "logger.my.project"

  containers:
  - name: cat-hosts
    image: busybox
    command:
    - cat
    args:
    - "/etc/hosts"
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, I actually tried it from that exact link in the ingress-nginx namespace but it didn't work for some reason. I have "default", "ingress-nginx", "kube-node-lease", "kube-public", "kube-system" namespaces. Still whenever I try to approach app.my.project via browser it should open the webpage, as it does on a local Linux computer; and it doesn't. Is it safe to delete all namespaces and just leave default OR should I just implement it on default?

Comment: added them to "default" "ingress-nginx" "kube-system" namespaces and they seem completed with a yellow exclamation point and readiness is 0/1 for them. I think this is normal because it runs once?